# How to Sync the Location After Getting Up from Ragdoll?

Tags: multiplayer, unreal-4, blueprints, synchronization, ragdoll

I am currently working on multiplayer fighting game and my game will have an anim->ragdoll when the player is knocked out and be able to getting up from it. My problem now is ragdoll is making my character to jitter so I have to disable Replication Movement during ragdoll and enabling it again after getting up from the ragdoll.

My problem now is I am having problem when the character is getting up after ragdoll, as soon I enabling Replication Movement again, the character is snapped back at the initial position before the ragdoll, even though I have set the character location and stuff.

[image]

Here is the bp that I set up the location and stuff
[image]

This is how I enabling back the replication movement after Getting Up anim is complete and this is where the problem exist.
[image]

I tried to set the location back to the current meshlocation that I recorded during the ragdoll mode which is run on tick but still the problem persist. Any ideas or suggestion for another approach to handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I will finally found a workaround after several hours of this question is posted. Almost a month trying to figure out how to solve it, I just found out that these two booleans exist that I managed to sync my character movement across all clients. I don't have to disable replication movement whatsoever. You can basically utilize this details on any ragdoll function in my opinion.

[image]